# Android ExpandableList Activity child's android:layout_weight not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-layout-weight

I'm facing a problem that's driving me mad. That's the thing. I have an expandable List Activity wich shows media files. One group are the audio files, the other group are the Image files. AudioGroup's children have one layout, ImageGroup's children have another different layout. This is the code I'm using

EXPANDABLE LIST ADAPTER, CHILDVIEW PART

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflaterChild=activity.getLayoutInflater(); 
    convertView=null;

    //seleccionamos el layout que nos convenga en funcion de si es audio o imagen

    //audio
    if(mediaObjects.get(groupPosition).getFiles().get(childPosition).getTipo()==1){
        viewChild=inflaterChild.inflate(R.layout.layout_child_media_musica, null);  
        descripcion=(TextView)viewChild.findViewById(R.id.descripcionMusica);
        descripcion.setText(Html.fromHtml(mediaObjects.get(groupPosition).getFiles().get(childPosition).getDescripcion()));
    }

    //imagen
    if(mediaObjects.get(groupPosition).getFiles().get(childPosition).getTipo()==2){         
        viewChild=inflaterChild.inflate(R.layout.layout_media_imagenes, null);              
        thumbnail=(ImageView)viewChild.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailMedia);
        thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.portada);
        descripcion=(TextView)viewChild.findViewById(R.id.descripcionImagen);
        descripcion.setText(Html.fromHtml(mediaObjects.get(groupPosition).getFiles().get(childPosition).getDescripcion()));
    }
    return viewChild;
}
```

LAYOUT FOR AUDIOGROUP

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".Media" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/childMediaMusica"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/descripcionMusica"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/contenedorBotones"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/playStop"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/down"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"/>        
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

LAYOUT FOR IMAGEGROUP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".Media" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailMedia"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="35"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/descripcionImagen"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>   

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see It's a very simple code. Well, that's the result:

[image]

AudioGroup layout is not filling the whole width.
ImageGroup layout is a mess, It's like It couldn't see the weights I wrote.

Does anyone know what the hell It's happening here?

Thing's I already tested:

- Every combination of fill_parent, match_parent, wrap_content etc on main LinearLayout in each layouts.
- Try do thing only using dp meassure (that works but's not the thing I want)
- Try using another image on ImageGroup layout
- Use the ViewHolder and convertView stuff to manage the layouts inside the getChildView method

Any of those things (except use the dp size) works, but I'm open to suggestions even If means do It again.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

JODERRR POR FIN!!!

Ok I just solved It. I took me other 3 f****** hours. It was simple as set correctly the ExpandibleList layout as that:

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

In a frist moment I had layout_width as wrap_content. I can't believe I didn't notice It before